# how do I make the hook modifier still work if the object moves location?

Tags: modifiers

I have assigned a hook modifier to an object with an empty but when the object moves the modifier's influence stays at the location it was created even if I move the empty with the object

Comment: Hello could you please show some pictures?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "the modifier's influence stays at the location"? An influence is nothing that can stay in a location. The object, parts of it like vertices or the empty can stay in a location. If you hooked the object's mesh or a vertex of it to an empty, then the vertex stays where the empty is, no matter where you move the object. It is not supposed to be the empty following the vertex. Or was your goal to _parent_ the object to the empty or vice versa instead of using a _Hook_ modifier?

Comment: You can parent the Hook to the modified object, so the Hook follows the object wherever it goes...